# Am I missing any muscle group in my upper body workout?

Tags: workout-routines, upper-body-workout

I usually do these five exercieses on my upper body training:

1. Dumbbell press
2. Dumbbell military press/Dumbbell Seated Overhead Press
3. Seated cable row
4. Lat pulldown
5. Dumbbell lateral rise

Is there any muscle groups/exercises that I should be doing?

Maybe some tricep extensions?

EDIT:
A bit of context on how much I train and my overall goals.

I'm trying to build some muscle and get in shape. However I don't train for hours nor I'm in the gym 7 times a week. I want to be realistic with what I can keep up with. I've been following this routine with some variations for a year and a half now, 2-3 times a week. I've done plenty of progress and I'm really satisfied. I just wanted to know if I could get a bit more out my training

Comment: Quite a few or very few depending. What are your fitness goals, what are you lifting for?

Comment: I'm trying to build some muscle and get in shape. However I don't train for hours nor I'm in the gym 7 times a week. I want to be realistic with what I can keep up with. I've been following this routine with some variations for a year and a half now, 2-3 times a week. I've done plenty of progress and I'm really satisfied. I just wanted to know if I could get a bit more out my training. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you consider upper body.

Arms are in the compounds but no direct work is being done. If you are not considering them as upper body, then you cover several muscles with the compounds, but similar to arms there is no isolation.

Some specifically I don’t see is rear delts, and traps which can be hit with compounds, but  respond most with direct exercise.

Comment: Would you recommend hitting any muscle group in isolation? I've been avoiding those as hitting all muscles groups would require much more time.

Comment: You don’t necessarily need any isolation. If you are making progress, and seeing results you want then keep doing what you enjoy, and what your body is responding to. For the sake of time compounds work great for hitting several muscles. If you wanted to incorporate the rear delts and traps, a variation of face pull can hit both at the same time, and can be super setted with a bigger compound because they take next to no energy out of you.

Comment: @DamiyenGee thanks a lot! I'll definitely give it a try!